# Resources Exceeded on simple query when using DAY() or DATE() functions

Tags: google-bigquery

This query runs fails with resources exceeded:

```
SELECT
  *,
  DAY(event_timestamp) as whywontitwork,
FROM
looker_scratch.LR_78W8A60O4MQ20L2U6OA5B_events_sql_doctor_activity
```

But this one works fine:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
looker_scratch.LR_78W8A60O4MQ20L2U6OA5B_events_sql_doctor_activity
```

The source table is 14m rows but I've run similar queries on much larger datasets before. We have large results enabled and have tried both flattened results and not (though there are no nested fields anyway). The error also occurs if you use the DATE() function instead of DAY(), or a REGEXP_EXTRACT() function

The job id is realself-main:bquijob_69e3a888_152f1fdc205.

Comment: Though I'm still investigating this, do you still get the same error selecting only the `DAY(event_timestamp)` without the `*` before it? Do you also consistently get this `Resources Exceeded` error?

Comment: It works if I remove the * before it. The Resources Exceeded error is consistent every time we try it but it may be a new bug as I suspect we've run similar queries before.

Answer (score 1):

You've hit an internal error in BigQuery. We tweaked our query engine's configuration at around 3pm (US Pacific Time) in an effort to prevent the error.

**Update**: After observing the error rate, it looks like this change has fixed the problem. If you see any other issues, please let us know. Note that StackOverflow is best for usage questions, but if you suspect a bug, you can file an issue at our [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list).