# BigQuery Internal Error or Resources Exceeded only when writing to table

Tags: google-bigquery

I've come across a strange issue with Google BigQuery where a query won't run if writing to a destination table (through the UI or API). The query does, however, work fine if I run from the UI and then use the "Save as Table" button to create a table.

This query fails with the error "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed." if writing to a destination table but it works fine if not. Here's a job id that failed: realself-main:bquijob_75b7040f_152f29c8619.

```
SELECT
  sponsorships.sponsorship_id AS sponsorship_id,
FROM rsdw.sponsorships sponsorships
  JOIN EACH rsdw.sponsorship_sku sponsorship_sku ON sponsorship_sku.sponsorship_sku_id = sponsorships.sponsorship_sku_id
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT
    dt
  FROM rsdw.calendar
  WHERE
    dt <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    and dt >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
  ) AS calendar
```

I tried simplifying the query and this version fails with a "Resources exceeded during query execution" error if writing to a table but works fine if not. A failing job id is realself-main:bquijob_75b7040f_152f29c8619.

```
SELECT
  sponsorships.sponsorship_id AS sponsorship_id,
FROM rsdw.sponsorships sponsorships
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT
    dt
  FROM rsdw.calendar
  WHERE
    dt <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    and dt >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
  ) calendar
```

Comment: Likely the same cause as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471150/resources-exceeded-on-simple-query-when-using-day-or-date-functions

Comment: Actually, the first query is now returning resources exceeded (e.g. realself-main:bquijob_3b7d5027_152fbd741d6). I'm sure I tested it this morning but I may have just tested the second one, which does now work.

Comment: Note that as before, it does work if not writing the results to a table.

Answer (score 2):

There was indeed a problem with your project on BigQuery side (hence "Internal error"). This problem should be fully resolved now, and your queries should work when writing to table.